# Merge DWGs to 1DWG and put all corresponding objects to one new layer named as the original filename

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

​I have 1000 dwg that has text and lines on 2 layer, i want to merge them all in one dwg and the final dwg should have as layer names all the filename and all the objects (text,lines) should be in only one layer which is the filename the come from.

e.g   t1.dwg, t2.dwg... -> merge.dwg (with two layer t1,t2...) every object from t1.dwg should be inside t1 layer in the merged dwg, same with the object from t2.dwg should be all inside t2 layer on the merged dwg, and so one for all the dwgs used as input.

Software used Fme Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure the dynamic schema option is selected for the workflow, this will read in all of your DWG files through a single reader and output through a single writer.

To create multiple layers per file rather than lots of separate files, you must fanout on feature type rather than a dataset fanout. Check out the explanation below:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/datainterop/mergedProjects/FME_Workbench/about_fanout.htm

Comment: But how shoud i map the schema so it group the autocad entities and put those on a layer with its filename

Comment: try this - https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/Workbench/Setting_Feature_Type_Fanout_Properties.htm

Comment: I get this error: Unable to dynamically create a layer for a feature whose feature-type (layer name) is blank!  Check that all your AutoCAD features have a valid layername

Comment: you may need to expose the fme_feature_type attribute on your reader

Comment: No, the problem is that the writer should not be dynamic

Comment: Did you use fme_feature_type attribute as the layer name?

Comment: I just used the autocad.basename

Comment: Sure, that works too. So just to clarify, I have explained that a dynamic workflow is required in order to have one reader and one writer. From there you will need to fanout on layer by using an attribute such as fme_feature_type for layer name. A dynamic schema on writer will force to write multiple DWG files if the schemas of the inputs are different, so this isn't what you want to use!